# Singular hypersurface section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth projective surface over complex numbers in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Let $\text{Spec}(R)$ be an affine open set of $X$. Then $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$ algebra of dimension $2$. Let $Z:= \{p_1, ...p_k\}$ be a set of distinct closed points in $\text{Spec}(R)$. Since $X$ is smooth, there are regular parameters $x_i, y_i$ such that the maximal ideal $m_{p_i}$ is generated by $x_i$ and $y_i$. Let $I$ be ideal defined by $m^{'}_{p_1}m^{'}_{p_2}...m^{'}_{p_k}$, where $m^{'}_{p_i} = \langle x_i^2, y_i\rangle$. Let $Z^{'}$ be the subscheme defined by $I$.

What is the geometric interpretation of $Z^{'}$ in terms of $Z$?

Is $Z^{'}$ locally complete intersection?

Suppose $Y \in H^0(I_{Z^{'}}(d))$ is a degree $d$ hypersurface section. Then can we say that $Y$ is singular along $Z$ ?

Comment: 1) By definition $Z'$ is locally a complete intersection: in a neighborhood of $p_i$ it is defined by $x_i^2=y_i=0.\quad\qquad \qquad$

2) The condition for a curve to belong to $\lvert I_{Z'}(d)\rvert$ is to pass through each $p_i$ and to be tangent at $p_i$ to the direction $y_i=0$. For $d\gg 0$ there will always exist smooth curves in $\lvert \mathscr{O}_X(d)\rvert$ with these properties.

Comment: I guess the degree of $Z^{'}$ is $2k$ and a general such point with the property as mentioned imposes $n +1$ conditions on degree $d$ hypersurfaces. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, the degree (more correctly the length) of $Z'$ is $2k$. I do not understand the second question; for $d\gg 0$, $Z'$ imposes $2k$ conditions on hypersurfaces of degree $d$.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. I got it. what happens if we replace the ideals  $<x_i^2, y_i>$, by the ideals, $<x_i^2, y_i^2 >$? I guess the length of $Z^{'}$ will be $3k$ and any hypersurface section passing through $Z^{'}$ should be singular along $Z$.

Comment: In particular if we treat $Z^{'}$ as subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$, then $Z^{'}$  imposes $k(n+1)$ conditions  on hypersurfaces of degree $d$ provided $Z$ is sufficiently general.

Comment: Yes for the first question, I don't understand the second one: is $Z'$ still contained in a smooth surface? It looks like you are just imposing your hypersurface to be singular along $Z$.

Comment: @abx: Not quite yes for the first question --- the length of $(x^2,y^2)$ is 4, so the length of such $Z'$ is $4k$.

Comment: @Sasha: Oops, yes of course. I read too fast, I thought it was $\mathfrak{m}_i^2$.

Comment: @abx: Yes. $Z^{'}$ is the subscheme of the smooth surface $X$ defined by $I$. Now a hypersurface section $ Y \in H^0(I_{Z^{'}}(d))$  is a singular curve along $Z$.  I guess it does not imply that the degree $d$ hypersurface is itself singular along $Z$. It is known that, a double point in $\mathbb{P}^n$ imposes $n+1$ conditions on forms of degree $d$. My question how many conditions a doule point in $X$ imposes on degree $d$ hypersurface section ? Is it possible to choose $Z$ such that if a hypersurface section is singular along $Z$ then the hypersurface  itself singular along $Z$ ?